# Bond characteristics using Bloomberg in Excel

Tags: fixed-income, bloomberg, excel

I would like to retrieve bond characteristics (bond type, coupon type etc.) for corporate bond ISINs using the Bloomberg Excel Addin.

I tried `=BDP("DE0001848083", "COUNTRY")` which did not work. ("COUNTRY" is just an example - I don't know if this field really exists).

What is the correct way to retrieve this data?

Comment: I'd directly contact Bloomberg support via your terminal.

Comment: I can access the terminal for only a very limited amount of time (ca. 1 hour) which means I need to have my excel sheets prepared in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that the code is an ISIN:

```
=BDP("DE0001848083 ISIN", "COUNTRY")
```

should work as expected.